# SSH error in connection to a new Domain

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

I was already able to connect to the server via `ssh` properly. But recently after changing the server fixed-IP address and domain name, I cannot connect to the server by DNS name. Despite, I can `ssh` to the server with its IP address. The error of `ssh` with domain name is the following:

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@       WARNING: POSSIBLE DNS SPOOFING DETECTED!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
The DSA host key for example.com has changed,
and the key for the corresponding IP address X.X.X.X
has a different value. This could either mean that
DNS SPOOFING is happening or the IP address for the host
and its host key have changed at the same time.
Offending key for IP in /home/.ssh/known_hosts:10
  remove with: ssh-keygen -f "/home/.ssh/known_hosts" -R X.X.X.X
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the DSA key sent by the remote host is
*:*:*:*:*:....
Please contact your system administrator.
Add correct host key in /home/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Offending DSA key in /home/.ssh/known_hosts:11
  remove with: ssh-keygen -f "/home/.ssh/known_hosts" -R example.com
DSA host key for example.com has changed and you have requested strict checking.
Host key verification failed.
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The answer is in the question:

```
ssh-keygen -f "/home/.ssh/known_hosts" -R example.com
```

You will get more info on the [first google hit](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/warning-remote-host-identification-has-changed-error-and-solution/) for the big message. `WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!`

Comment: Thanks, I was in doubt whether it could be the right solution or not.

Comment: Since you know that the IP changed, the message can be ignored, although the best way to react to such message is to contact the system administrator of the server and ask them whether the key fingerprint is correct or not.

Comment: Very offtopic but, who the hell wrote this message? This occures in my terminal and iTerm. Really like the man-in-the-middle... I'm waiting for his attack

Comment: This solution didn't work for me so I am downvoting. Sorry

Comment: Well I receive the very same message as in question. I've added the key to known_hosts and has ran your command. Nothing has changed. So I am pretty sure that description of my problem would be the same. However there might be more solution than one to this. I will edit and update your answer once I will fix my issue

Comment: @kukis The problem is not to add the key to known_host it is to remove the previously stored one for that same host/address

Comment: But when I do not have any key for this host in known_hosts file then your command fails with message: Host somehost.somedomain.com not found in known_hosts

Comment: @kukis if you do not have any key for this host in known_host, then you cannot have the error message displayed in the question.

Comment: I went to https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/warning-remote-host-identification-has-changed-error-and-solution/ and tried `Solution #1: Remove keys using ssh-keygen`. That was the solution for me. Thank you.

Comment: I just deleted the line of `example.com` from `/home/.ssh/known_hosts` and ssh-ed again

Answer (score 5):

You should remove line 10 from your known_hosts because the system signalized you about the problem
Offending key for IP in /home/.ssh/known_hosts:10

Comment: It works for me. Because, with other commands I got the message: do_known_hosts: hostkeys_foreach failed: No such file or directory
. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I moved my `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file and retried it worked. I guess the effect will just confirmation prompt for future connections, for the hosts that are there in `known_hosts`

Answer (score 2):

I faced same problem when I tried to do a pull.

Fix:
I deleted .ssh/known_hosts file on my system and retried pull, it worked.

Why this happened:
We had a gitlab migration. known_host file store gitlab ip, so it was not able to establish connectivity with existing host.

Answer (score 1):

If you have got a backup of your ***/etc/ssh*** directory and want to restore it, just use

```
ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@hostname
```

for connecting once without checking.

Source: [ssh man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh)

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem.

I think the problem is that the item recorded in the "known-hosts" does not match something of the remote host(sorry, I don't know what the something is).

In my case, I just deleted the item in "known-hosts" according to the IP address of the remote host and ran ssh command again. Then it worked.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what the problem with this comment. I encountered the same question and I post my work around. That's what I did. If you think my comment has a problem, could you point it out with details please? Because I don't understand why this does not really answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Just follow what is suggested.

`sudo ssh-keygen -f "/root/.ssh/known_hosts" -R ip`

`sudo ssh-keygen -f "/root/.ssh/known_hosts" -R host`

These commands will remove old fingerprints, and then you will be asked:

> The authenticity of host 'host (ip)' can't be established.
>       ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:YrD+1E4JmdeObwEyQW3zGqNhXE//64MMZrHHaInE7w0.
>       Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?

Write "yes" and you will see such message:

> Warning: Permanently added 'host,ip' (ECDSA)
>   to the list of known hosts.

This will create new fingerprint in the `/root/.ssh/known_hosts` file.

Comment: *Warning danger ahead*. You must confirm that the fingerprint shown is legitimate, via another channel. Else, you might happen to be a victim of a man-in-the-middle. And answering "yes" in that case confirms that situation as normal. The illusion of security. "Most of the time" the fingerprint will be legitimate, but you must check it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it couldn't find the file so I had to flip the file path and domain name like so:

```
ssh-keygen -R example.com -f ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Answer (score -1):

Just delete the known_hosts file

```
$ rm .ssh/known_hosts
$ ssh ras.mydomain.com
```

Try connecting with ssh again

```
ssh username@server-ip-here
```

Comment: You'd also be deleting all the other lines in `~/.ssh/known_hosts`, containing the public keys of other servers, which is probably not what a user wants to do in this case.